# How to Solve NoClassDefFound error in android studio while connecting with mongodb?

Tags: android, mongodb, android-studio

I have a cluster in `mongodb` atlas and I am trying to connect with the database from my android app. But  I am getting `"noclassdeffound"` error. I have tried both `mongo-driver` and `mongo-java-driver` in the dependency. What's going wrong? Is there any solution?

Comment: post your error as well